# How to differenciate a not assigned public int property new instance object from an assigned one

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, unassigned-variable

Lets have a simple class with an int property

```
    public class SimpleClass {
      public int myInt { get; set; }// for having a property and not "public int myInt;", see Jon Skeet remark
    }
```

I instanciate it twice assigning myInt or not

```
    assignedObject = new SimpleClass() { myInt=0};
    notAssignedObject = new SimpleClass();
```

Now by reflection, I query the value of myInt in each case using

```
    Object value;
    value=assignedObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(o=>o.Name.Equals("myInt")).First().GetValue(assignedObject,null)
    value=notAssignedObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(o=>o.Name.Equals("myInt")).First().GetValue(notAssignedObject,null)
```

I am getting twice 0 for myInt, but I need to be able to differenciate them. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have code to specifically *remember* the difference between a property which has been initialized with its default value, and one which hasn't been set at all, you can't tell the difference. I have two suggestions, however:

- You could make it an `int?` property, and then check whether the value is `null`. Of course, it's possible for it to be set to `null` explicitly, unless you prohibit that, but it may be good enough.
- You could keep a separate `bool` value to know whether or not it's been set explicitly, and just set it in your property setter, along with the value.

Sample code for the second option:

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    private int value;
    private bool valueSet;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.valueSet = true;
        }
    }

    public bool ValueSet { get { return valueSet; } }
}
```

Comment: I have corrected SimpleClass and put myInt as a property.Thanks. Using int? seems not adapted since SimpleClass targets a database model. Need to think about putting it explicitely to null but I just realize that I use such properties as fields. The second possibility is a bit overhead since I target many properties.

Comment: @thipages: I'm not sure what you mean by "I use such properties as fields". To be honest, it's not really clear what your requirements are - and they certainly weren't clear from the question - but *in general* there's no difference between a property which has been set to the default value for that type, and one which hasn't been set at all.

Comment: "I use such properties as fields", I meant that I declare public myInt{get;set;} and use it in my code as it were declared as public int myInt; "but in general there's no difference..." answers my question.

Comment: @thipages: Right - you mean "I usually just declare automatically implemented properties." (That's what that syntax is called.) It's not the same as declaring a public field though, in various ways. (For example, you can pass a field by reference, but not a property.)